# php attach multiple variable with insertQuery mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Getting value from jquery to php. 
MySQL table has q1, q2, q3... columns.
I need qValNew be q(depending the qVal from jquery)

```
$qVal = $_GET["qVal"];

$qValNew = "q{$qVal}";

$insertQuery="UPDATE tableName SET $qValNew='" .addslashes($qAns). "' WHERE fullName='".addslashes($fullName)."' and section_id='".addslashes($cID)."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $insertQuery);
        }
```

Problem area is here:

UPDATE tableName SET $qValNew='" .addslashes($qAns). "'

if I change $qValNew to q1='" .addslashes($qAns)."' works fine.
but not with $qValNew.

Any suggestion...

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I think you forgot your actual question

Comment: `$qValNew = "q[$qVal]";` should probably just be `$qValNew = "q{$qVal}";`

Comment: `addslashes()` is about as useful for preventing sql injection attacks as a piece of wet toiler paper is in drying out a swimming pool.

Comment: @MarcB  Why would you use 'wet' toilet paper?  That doesn't make sense.  You should use dry?  Am I am missing something?

Comment: @tetary: it's intended to illustrate the ludicriousness of OP's code. "Look at me, i'm totally safe from shooting myself in the head. I don't need to check if this gun is unloaded. *BLAM**sploosh**"

Comment: Thanks Dave, but still not saving data on q1 or any column.

Comment: There really is no excuse for using MySQLi and then injecting data values from a user input form directly into the query.... __use bind variables__

Comment: Thanks Dave, Fixed that issue.